# Dynamic T-SQL query for attaching AD group depending on the domain (TEST or PROD)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have two domains, `Test` and `Prod`.

I would like to have a dynamic SQL Server stored procedure where it can add the AD group to the server depending on which domain you are in.

Comment: Do you want to create a login in SQL Server for one AD group or another, depending on the domain which the server is joined to?

Comment: Maybe the `DEFAULT_DOMAIN()` function could help.